# What is SessionState customProvider

Tags: asp.net, session

I have the following code from my web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
   </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Now I want to extend my session timeout to 1 hour.

```
<sessionState timeout = "60" mode = "InProc" />
```

**Now my problem is**
Is it ok to delete the customProvider from my original code and just add timeout="60" instead? I dont know whats that customProvider for.

Would it not do any harm from my application?

or mixing both is fine.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
   </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ok to delete it or comment it out. When you specify mode as InProc, ASP.NET will ignore the connection string details which are not even for storing session info anyway.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704356/the-sessionstate-timeout-doesnt-work-with-the-defaultsessionprovider)